# Insert object in an ordered list basing on an attribute of the objects

Tags: python

I'm developing a project for university. I have an ordered list of objects Node and I would like to insert a node in the right position, on the base of its attribute node.evaluation_function.

At the moment every time I insert a new node I order the list in this way:

```
queue.append(node)
queue.sort(key=lambda x: x.evaluation_function)
```

But I think this method is too slow because it reorders the list at every new insertion. 
Is there a method to insert the object immediately at the right position?

Answer (score 2):

One clean way would be to make these `node` objects comparable and use the `insort` functionality from [the `bisect` base-library](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/bisect.html).

```
from bisect import insort

class Node:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x

    def evaluation_function(self):
        return self.val

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.evaluation_function() < other.evaluation_function()


my_list = [Node(4), Node(6), Node(9)]
insort(my_list, Node(5))  

print([n.val for n in my_list])
```

Output:

```
[4, 5, 6, 9]
```

By defining the `__lt__(self, other)` function we make this class comparable. Then we can use the nice `insort` function to insert while keeping the order.

Comment: Thank you very much!! :)